# Is possible reach the DFT if I have the DTFT?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft, dtft

My teacher told me that DFT is DTFT sampled, i.e.:

$$X[k] = X(e^{j \omega})\Bigg|_{\omega = \frac{2\pi k}{N}}$$

But, if I have the sine

$$ x[n] = \sin(\omega_0 n) $$

the DTFT is:

$$X(e^{j \omega}) = \frac{\pi}{j} \big(\delta(\omega - \omega_0) - \delta(\omega + \omega_0)\big)$$

(periodic in $\omega$ with period $2\pi$). How is it possible to reconcile this with the DFT for $N$ values for this sine or any signal?

Thanks people. Sorry for the English.

Comment: this is a **good** question.  and Kaorthraya, your English is fine.

Comment: them Dirac delta *"functions"*.  them's a bitch!

Comment: Robert, I'd like to thank you for the help editing the question, now it is much better. And yes, Dirac delta are some sort of crazy things!

Comment: Could you please clarify which reconcilement you are looking for?

Comment: Hi AlexTP. I'll try to be more clear. If I have the DTFT of a signal $x[n]$, is it possible that I find the coefficients $X[k]$ for $k = [0, N-1]$ of DFT of this function, only by his DTFT? In other form, can I obtain the values of DFT starting from a DTFT of a signal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DFT is a sampled version of the DTFT only for *finite length* signals. Otherwise, there is no point in comparing the DTFT with the DFT because you can only compute the DFT for finite length (or periodic) signals. Your example $x[n]=\sin(\omega_0n)$ is an infinitely long sequence. For specific choices of $\omega_0$ it is periodic, but nevertheless, you can't obtain its DFT by sampling its DTFT. The operation of sampling a Dirac impulse is undefined because $\delta(\omega)$ cannot be evaluated at $\omega=0$ since the Dirac impulse is not an ordinary function but a distribution.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, for your answer, So, I only can make the process of sampling the DTFT for signal who have a finite lenght, ok? i.e:

$x [n] = \alpha^n[u[n] - u[n-n_0], n_0 > 0 $

have,


$X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1 - (\alpha e^{-j\omega})^{n_{0}}}{1 - \alpha^{-j\omega}}, |\alpha e^{-j \omega}|<1$

So, in this case I can substitute the $\omega = \frac{2\pi k}{N}$?

Comment: @Kaorthraya: yes, for finite length signals that should work.

Comment: @MattL., isn't $x[n]=\sin(\omega_0 n)$ periodic?  at least if $\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0} = \frac{N}{k} \qquad N,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, isn't it even periodic for discrete-time $x[n]$?  how is it that $$X[k] = X(e^{j \omega})\Bigg|_{\omega = \frac{2\pi k}{N}}$$ even with the Diracs in there?  That question remains unanswered.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: $\sin(\omega_0n)$ is periodic if $\omega_0$ is a rational  multiple of $2\pi$, as you suggested. But that has no bearing on the relation between the DTFT and the DFT. The signal $x[n]=\sin(\omega_0n)$ is infinitely long, and that relation between the DTFT and the DFT only holds for signals of finite length.

Comment: @MattL. I had tested this concepts in MatLab, i tried to sample in $\omega$, the location of samples makes sense considering my tests, but the amplitude of samples is totally wrong, as expected. In truly, it's can be predicted, because the delta of Dirac in $\omega$ domain is multiplied by a $\pi$, but when I do the DFT the amplitude is $\frac{N}{2}$